# Trying to determine how to do a case insensitive sort on sheets for input to an HTML select options list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of items in one column on a sheets tab which will be used as select options for an item in the sidebar form. It works fine except when I try to do a case insensitive sort before supplying the options array to HTML. I have done some searching on the web and found some approaches but not able to get anything to work so far. Any help would be appreciated. I dumped the array being delivered to HTML via console.log and it had a structure of
[[str1],[str2],[str3]]
here is sample code of my understanding of the problem.

```
function doubleDimension () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Notes");
  dList = sheet.getRange(4,3,4).getValues();
  console.log(dList);
  // output is [ [ 'apple' ], [ 'Orange' ], [ 'carrots' ], [ 'Dulce de Leche' ] ]
  dList.push(["cherry"]);
  dList.sort(function(x, y){
      x = x.toLowerCase()
      y = y.toLowerCase()
      if (x < y) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (x > y) {
        return 1;
      }
       return 0;
    });
  console.log(dList);
  /* output for the straight sort is
      [ [ 'Dulce de Leche' ],
      [ 'Orange' ],
      [ 'apple' ],
      [ 'carrots' ],
      [ 'cherry' ] ]
  */
  /* attemopted a case insensitive sort using web suggestions. output below
        Error   TypeError: x.toLowerCase is not a function
              (anonymous)   @ code.gs:29
              doubleDimension   @ code.gs:28  TypeError: x.toLowerCase is not a function
  */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to cobble together a solution. Not sure if I completely understand it. I had to create an array of strings using the following code.

```
 dList = sheet.getRange(4,3,4).getValues().join().split(',');
```

Then do the sort on the string array where the toLowerCase method worked. Then rebuild the array with the following for loop.

```
for ( i = 0; i < dList.length; ++i) {
      optionsList[i] = [dList[i]];
    }
```